# Need help in figuring out the error "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Module' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have created a simple asp.net core 6.0 and I am trying to simply read in a simple Model using javascript but I am getting the following error:

***JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Module' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. Path 'PageContext.ActionDescriptor.HandlerMethods[0].MethodInfo.Module.Assembly.EntryPoint'.***

I have researched what the error is and understand it but I definitely don't have a recurring class reference. My Model only has one field as shown below. How would I read the Model using Javascript or read a field from the Model using javascript/jquery

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var foo = @Json.Serialize(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml });

    </script>
}
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
```

I have added the following to the **Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
       Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

My **Model** is very simple as shown below

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string? Title {get;set;}
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Title = "Index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Model` object inherits from [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which has a lot complexity in it. This class includes the whole HttpContext, and especially the HttpResponse that is not yet serializable, since you haven't finished telling Razor what to put in the response. It also includes the user's principal, object cycles and some non-serializable objects. The error given above especially focuses on a specific path which basically includes your whole dll (`Assembly`) reflection model.

It is not very clear why you try to exchange data from the server to the client by writing directly to the client 's javascript sources. This looks like a very inappropriate usage of the engine. Razor pages is designed for monolithic architecture, where you generate page *with* contents server-side. In that architecture, javascript is limited to a rather cosmetic usage, and is not intended to access data structures. If you want to exchange data from the server with the javascript stack, you should consider a better communication channel, such as an external JSON file in `/wwwroot` for static content, or exposing a WebAPI endpoint for dynamic content. Razor pages is probably not the best stack to develop such an application though.

In any case, you should always serialize or deserialize structures with as few technical features included as possible. If you really need to serialize data from your Model, make a specific class/record type designed for serialization:

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexDTO Data { get; set; } = new IndexDTO();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Data.Title = "Index";
    }
}
```

**IndexDTO.cs**

```cs
public class IndexDTO
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var foo = @Json.Serialize(Model.Data, new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml });

    </script>
}
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Data.Title)
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, yes you are right I  wouldn't do this in a real application but was just curious, anyway thank you for your in-depth explanation. I will mark your answer as "solved". Thank you